# MyLinearLayout.getDrawingCache() gives a NullPointerException

Tags: android

edit:

**Nevermind, got it working that way**

```
TopRatedPage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
TopRatedPage.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
TopRatedPage.layout(0, 0, TopRatedPage.getMeasuredWidth(), TopRatedPage.getMeasuredHeight()); 
TopRatedPage.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(TopRatedPage.getDrawingCache());
TopRatedPage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

---

old:

I'm trying to take a screenshot from a layout, like so.

```
LinearLayout TopRatedPage = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.toprated, null);
...
Bitmap screenshot;
TopRatedPage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(TopRatedPage.getDrawingCache()); // Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
TopRatedPage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Thanks!

edit:
also tried like this, it doesn't throw an error, but given an empty bitmap.

```
Bitmap screenshot = TopRatedPage.getDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know what happen..

```
LinearLayout TopRatedPage = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.toprated, null);
Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(LinearLayout .getWidth(), LinearLayout .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(screenshot);
LinearLayout.draw(c);
imageView.setImageBitmap(screenshot);
```

Also if possible, use,

```
View captureView = null;
captureView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toprated, null);
Bitmap screenshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(captureView.getWidth(), captureView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(screenshot);
captureView .draw(c);
imageView.setImageBitmap(screenshot);
```

Comment: Thanks man, already got it working with those MeasureSpec. Appears that without them the bitmap was 0x0 in size. :)